# RxJava RetryWhen, This processor allows only a single Subscriber

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am learning how to do data polling in RxJava2

Here is my code so far.

```
 private io.reactivex.Single<String> getMyTask() {
        return io.reactivex.Single.fromCallable(new Callable<String>() {
            @Override
            public String call() throws Exception {
                Log.d("ERSEN","Task Started!");
                Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

                if(random.nextBoolean()){
                    return "WORK COMPLETED";
                }
                Log.d("ERSEN","Task Had An Error!");
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        });
    }
```

The above is my `Single` which emits a `String` basically simulating some work.
I also make the task randomly succeed and fail to the test the case when a poll event fails to check if re-subscription occurs correctly

**My problem**

```
 compositeDisposable.add(getMyTask()
                .repeatWhen(new Function<Flowable<Object>, Publisher<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<?> apply(final Flowable<Object> objectFlowable) throws Exception {
                        return objectFlowable.delay(INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                })
                .retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> throwableFlowable.flatMap(new Function<Throwable, Publisher<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Publisher<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                        if (throwable instanceof ClassCastException) {
                            return Flowable.error(throwable);
                        }
                        return throwableFlowable.delay(INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    }
                }))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(this::onSuccess, this::onError));
```

In the above, I am resubscribing to the `Observable` when it emitted some data successfully. 
I am having problems with `retryWhen`.

For this example I wish to not retry if a `ClassCastException` occurs.
In my `Observable` this is not produced which is for a reason because I am testing the logic to retry only on certain errors

However, I am reviving this error with the above code when an error in the `Observable` is produced

```
This processor allows only a single Subscriber
```

I am not sure what is wrong, I have been following this blog post

http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

Thanks for reading
Let me know if you would like me to post any more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are resubscribing to the error flow in your `retryWhen` which is not allowed and doesn't make sense in your situation. You should delay a value in `flatMap` instead:

```java
    .retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> throwableFlowable.flatMap(
        new Function<Throwable, Publisher<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Publisher<?> apply(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                if (throwable instanceof ClassCastException) {
                    return Flowable.error(throwable);
                }
                return Flowable.just("ignored").delay(INTERVAL, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            }
        }
    ))
```

Comment: The perfect answer! Had the same issue and Flowable.just(0).delay(...) works as should.